# Using PHP and Doctrine 2 is there a way to implement your own collections for retrieved data?

Tags: inheritance, collections, doctrine-orm

When creating a collection inside an entity you initialise it as an `ArrayCollection` in the constructor. `ArrayCollection` can be extended and those children used in it's place. Howerver, When the entity is retrieved from the database the `ArrayCollection` is swapped for a `PersistentCollection` which implements the same interface as `ArrayCollection` but is marked as `final`.

Is there a way of implementing your own collection class that when retrieving data from the database allows you to use custom collection methods for sorting and retrieving items from the collection.

P.S. I don't want to modify the Doctrine source itself.

Comment: This is interesting, I assumed doctrine would load the data into the collection type I declared on my entities construction. This clearly isn't the case. And it appears all the methods filter, add etc are just duplicated into the PersistentCollection class. It would certainly be useful if you could create your own collection logic. I hope someone can help with this.

Answer (score 1):

What i did was is modify my public getCollection method.

```php
private $collectionOfStuff; //this is a subclassed Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection (MyCustomCollectionType in this case)

public function getCollectionOfStuff() {
   if (!$this->collectionOfStuff instanceof MyCustomCollectionType) {
        $this->collectionOfStuff = new MyCustomCollectionType($this->collectionOfStuff->toArray());
    }

    return $this->collectionOfStuff;
}
```

Afterwards you'll have to use $this->getCollectionOfStuff() to work your magic.

It is not the best solution (i've could've build a proxy or some sorts) but as subclassing the ArrayCollection is not supported by doctrine yet, it was for me the fastest/easiest fix.